# ItextPdf VerifyError in Android

Tags: android, itext, xmlworker

I am adding itextpdf library and worker library in my project for converting string **html** file content to **pdf** file but, getting below error

> java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName'

Also i have try with adding library and compile depedency way but getting same error 
case 1:

```
compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.5.6.jar')
compile files('libs/xmlworker-5.5.6.jar')
```

case 2:

```
compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.0.6'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf.tool/xmlworker
compile group: 'com.itextpdf.tool', name: 'xmlworker', version: '5.4.1'
```

How to resolve java.lang.verifyerror in android studio (Runtime error)?

**Edit:**

I have also tried:

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
compile 'com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:5.5.9'
```

Answer (score 0):

can u try this `compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'`

Comment: This does, I have recently used itext in my project and this was working fine